# Update Order Item: Value not updated

Tags: magento2, orders

```
public function getModel($class){
        $ObjectManager = ObjectManager::getInstance();
        return $ObjectManager->create($class);
    }
    public function updateOrderItemCalculation($item,$orderItem,$product=null,$itemPrice,$itemPrincipalPromo,$itemMainPrice){

        if(isset($product)){
            $item['product_id'] =  $product->getID();
            $item['product_type'] =  $product->getTypeId(); 
            $item['weight'] =  $product->getWeight();
            $item['is_virtual'] =  $product->getIsVirtual();
            $item['sku'] =  $product->getSku();
            $item['name'] =  $product->getName();
            $item['description'] =  $product->getDescription(); 
        }
        $item['qty_ordered'] =  $orderItem['Quantity'];
        $item['price'] =  $itemPrice;
        $item['base_price'] =  $itemPrice;
        $item['original_price'] =  $itemPrice;
        $item['base_original_price'] =  $itemPrice;

        $item['base_price_incl_tax'] =  $itemPrice;
        $item['price_incl_tax'] =  $itemPrice;

        $item['discount_amount'] =   $itemPrincipalPromo;
        $item['base_discount_amount'] =   $itemPrincipalPromo;          
        $item['row_total'] =   $itemMainPrice;
        $item['base_row_total_incl_tax'] =   $itemMainPrice;
        $item['row_total_incl_tax'] =   $itemMainPrice;

        $item['base_row_total'] =   ( $itemMainPrice) ;

        try {
            $saveItem = $this->getModel('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item')->load($item['item_id']);
            $saveItem->setData($item); 
            $saveItem->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
        unset($item);

    }
```

If i break code using `die();` then it works. I tried to debug many times but no results.

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2 modules should interact  with each other via [service contracts](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/design-patterns.html) (if available). Try to use [order item repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Api/OrderItemRepositoryInterface.php) instead of direct operations with order item model.

Comment: Can you tell me how can there we use repository

Comment: Inject order item repository interface and order item factory as dependencies via construct. Use factory to create new item object, then set all necessary data and save it using repository. If working with existing item, load it using repository instead of creating with factory. See how this is done for customer https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php